# removing edges from a completely connected graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How many number of edges can be removed from a given completely connected graph, such that there is at least one vertex with degree `D`?

This is not a homework question.

My thoughts: Is the answer V - D?

Comment: What is the definition of a "completely connected" graph? I know what a complete graph is, and what a connected graph is, but I've never heard of a "completely connected graph" before.

Comment: It is also called fully connected graph, every vertex is connected to every other vertex in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Degree of any vertex in a complete graph is $V-1$. We are removing edges. If all the edges are removed from different different vertices instead of a single vertex,then we will not get degree d of a single vertex in minimum number of removals.

So we will remove the edges from only a single vertex. Your answer is slightly wrong. Answer should be $$V-1-D$$.